# 404 issue of JiraTestResultReporter plugin configuration in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jira

It shows 404 error of JiraTestResultReporter configuration in Jenkins when I added the Jira URL "http://localhost:8080" which is hosted locally and clicked validation button.
My Jenkins server is also hosted locally and URL is "http://localhost:9091" which is run from blue-ocean docker file.

I tried a few ways as per below. But still has a problem.

- Changing port for Jira
- Restarting both Jira and Jenkins

My expected result would be a successful validation for this Jira URL when I do the validation.

I would very much appreciate if someone suggests upon this problem.